# Java Hadoop MapReduce Multiple Value

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to do a movie recommendation system and have been following this website. [LinkHere](http://aimotion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/introduction-to-recommendations-with.html)

```
def count_ratings_users_freq(self, user_id, values):
"""
For each user, emit a row containing their "postings"
(item,rating pairs)
Also emit user rating sum and count for use later steps.
output:
userid, number of movie rated by user, rating number count, (movieid, movie rating)

17    1,3,(70,3)
35    1,1,(21,1)
49    3,7,(19,2 21,1 70,4)
87    2,3,(19,1 21,2)
98    1,2,(19,2)
"""
item_count = 0
item_sum = 0
final = []
for item_id, rating in values:
    item_count += 1
    item_sum += rating
    final.append((item_id, rating))

yield user_id, (item_count, item_sum, final)
```

Is it possible to translate the above code to Java with Hadoop Map and Reduce?
`userid` as key
`no. movie rated by user, rating number count, (movieid, movie ratings)` as value.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting as the output?

Comment: basically just like the example above. `17    1,3,(70,3)` `userid, movie rated by user, rating number count, (movieid, movie rating`

Comment: I am sorry. It is not clear, what is the input and what is the output that you are expecting. If you just want the output to be equal to input, then why do you need MapReduce?

Comment: sorry. the input is `userid, movieid, ratings` So I would like to count the number of movies that 1 user rated.

Comment: So, for e.g. if input is (userid, movie id, movie rating) = (17, 70, 3), then the output will be (userId, no. of movies rated by user, rating number count, (movie id, movie ratings) = (17,1,3,(70,3))

Comment: yes thats what i am trying to do. I am thinking of doing one Map Reduce class for counting userid. One class for checking the movieid with userid. Then joining both data together. Just wondering if there is a quicker way of doing it.

Comment: You can make use of this [link](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/12/joining-two-files-using-multipleinput.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can convert this into a map reduce program.

**The mapper logic:**

1. Assuming that input will be of format (user ID, movie ID, movie rating) (for e.g. 17,70,3), you can split each line on comma (,) and emit "user ID" as key and (movie ID, movie rating) as value. For e.g. for the record: (17,70,3), you can emit key: (17) and value: (70,3)

**The reducer logic:**

1. You will keep 3 variables: movieCount (integer), movieRatingCount (integer), movieValues (string).
2. For each value, you need parse the value and get the "movie rating". For e.g for value (70,3), you will parse the movie rating = 3.
3. For each valid record, you will increment movieCount. You will add the parsed "movie rating" to "movieRatingCount" and append the value to "movieValues" string.

You will get the desired output.

Following is the piece of code, which achieves this:

```
package com.myorg.hadooptests;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MovieRatings {


    public static class MovieRatingsMapper
            extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text , IntWritable, Text>{

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String valueStr = value.toString();
            int index = valueStr.indexOf(',');

            if(index != -1) {
                try
                {
                    IntWritable keyUserID = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(valueStr.substring(0, index)));
                    context.write(keyUserID, new Text(valueStr.substring(index + 1)));
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    // You could get a NumberFormatException
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class MovieRatingsReducer
            extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
                           Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int movieCount = 0;
            int movieRatingCount = 0;
            String movieValues = "";

            for (Text value : values) {
                String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");
                if(tokens.length == 2)
                {
                    movieRatingCount += Integer.parseInt(tokens[1].trim()); // You could get a NumberFormatException
                    movieCount++;
                    movieValues = movieValues.concat(value.toString() + " ");
                }
            }

            context.write(key, new Text(Integer.toString(movieCount) + "," + Integer.toString(movieRatingCount) + ",(" + movieValues.trim() + ")"));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "CompositeKeyExample");
        job.setJarByClass(MovieRatings.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MovieRatingsMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MovieRatingsReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/in/in2.txt"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/out/"));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1);

    }
}
```

For the input:

```
17,70,3
35,21,1
49,19,2
49,21,1
49,70,4
87,19,1
87,21,2
98,19,2
```

I got the output:

```
17      1,3,(70,3)
35      1,1,(21,1)
49      3,7,(70,4 21,1  19,2)
87      2,3,(21,2 19,1)
98      1,2,(19,2)
```